# Only a single quartz thread being used at a time

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, quartz-scheduler, quartz, delayed-execution

We are using quartz-scheduler for scheduling around 500 jobs of Run-once type scheduled for the same time. We are observing the following behaviour-

Although there are 10 threads present in quartz scheduler(org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount), only a single worker thread executes sequentially at a particular instance of time eg- if a worker thread-1 is performing a task of processing an event, it would complete it first and then the other thread would start with the same.(This behaviour is observed even when we are not using @DisallowConcurrentExecution annotation)

We wanted to understand why is such behaviour being observed and how can we utilise all the threads that are present in the threadpool to improve the performance.

Parameters used:

1. clusterCheckinInterval - 120000
2. isClustered - true
3. misfireThreshold - 60000
4. useProperties - false
5. instanceId - AUTO
6. threadCount -10
7. threadPriority - 5

Versions used -

1. quartz-scheduler - 2.3.2
2. spring-boot - 1.2.4
3. spring-context-support - 5.2.1

Logs-

```
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:04:00.175","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-7","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Execute method of quartz started:WFD-109904, scheduled fire time:  Tue Mar 23 09:04:00 UTC 2021  current fire time:  Tue Mar 23 09:04:00 UTC 2021 JobDetail 'Event Manager:NULL.Event ManagerTask ID:27:NULL':  jobClass: 'com.xxx.KJob concurrentExectionDisallowed: false persistJobDataAfterExecution: false isDurable: true requestsRecovers: false   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:04:00.177","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-7->ThreadContext(ThreadStartTime=2021-03-23 09:04:00)","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Putting keys:WFD-109904  task id is:  27 current time is:  1616490240177   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:04:00.179","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-7->ThreadContext(ThreadStartTime=2021-03-23 09:04:00)","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Put operation  completed:WFD-109904  task id is:  27 current time is:  1616490240179   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:04:00.179","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-7->ThreadContext(ThreadStartTime=2021-03-23 09:04:00)","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Sending message  :WFD-109904  task id is:  27 current time is:  1616490240179   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:04:00.183","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-7->ThreadContext(ThreadStartTime=2021-03-23 09:04:00)","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Message sent  :WFD-109904  task id is:  27 current time is:  1616490240183   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:04:00.183","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-7","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Execute method of quartz completed:WFD-109904, scheduled fire time:  Tue Mar 23 09:04:00 UTC 2021  current fire time:  Tue Mar 23 09:04:00 UTC 2021 JobDetail 'Event Manager:NULL.Event ManagerTask ID:27:NULL':  jobClass: 'com.xxx.KJob concurrentExectionDisallowed: false persistJobDataAfterExecution: false isDurable: true requestsRecovers: false   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:04:00.820","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-1","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Execute method of quartz started:WFD-109904, scheduled fire time:  Tue Mar 23 09:04:00 UTC 2021  current fire time:  Tue Mar 23 09:04:00 UTC 2021 JobDetail 'Event Manager:NULL.Event ManagerTask ID:4:NULL':  jobClass: 'com.xxx.KJob concurrentExectionDisallowed: false persistJobDataAfterExecution: false isDurable: true requestsRecovers: false   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:04:00.821","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-1->ThreadContext(ThreadStartTime=2021-03-23 09:04:00)","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Putting keys:WFD-109904  task id is:  4 current time is:  1616490240821   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:04:00.822","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-1->ThreadContext(ThreadStartTime=2021-03-23 09:04:00)","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Put operation  completed:WFD-109904  task id is:  4 current time is:  1616490240822   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:04:00.822","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-1->ThreadContext(ThreadStartTime=2021-03-23 09:04:00)","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Sending message  :WFD-109904  task id is:  4 current time is:  1616490240822   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:04:00.826","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-1->ThreadContext(ThreadStartTime=2021-03-23 09:04:00)","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Message sent  :WFD-109904  task id is:  4 current time is:  1616490240826   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:04:00.827","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-1","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Execute method of quartz completed:WFD-109904, scheduled fire time:  Tue Mar 23 09:04:00 UTC 2021  current fire time:  Tue Mar 23 09:04:00 UTC 2021 JobDetail 'Event Manager:NULL.Event ManagerTask ID:4:NULL':  jobClass: 'com.xxx.KJob concurrentExectionDisallowed: false persistJobDataAfterExecution: false isDurable: true requestsRecovers: false   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:04:01.769","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-4","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Execute method of quartz started:WFD-109904, scheduled fire time:  Tue Mar 23 09:04:00 UTC 2021  current fire time:  Tue Mar 23 09:04:01 UTC 2021 JobDetail 'Event Manager:NULL.Event ManagerTask ID:7:NULL':  jobClass: 'com.xxx.KJob concurrentExectionDisallowed: false persistJobDataAfterExecution: false isDurable: true requestsRecovers: false   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:04:01.770","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-4->ThreadContext(ThreadStartTime=2021-03-23 09:04:01)","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Putting keys:WFD-109904  task id is:  7 current time is:  1616490241770   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:04:01.772","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-4->ThreadContext(ThreadStartTime=2021-03-23 09:04:01)","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Put operation  completed:WFD-109904  task id is:  7 current time is:  1616490241772   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:04:01.772","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-4->ThreadContext(ThreadStartTime=2021-03-23 09:04:01)","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Sending message  :WFD-109904  task id is:  7 current time is:  1616490241772   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:04:01.784","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-4->ThreadContext(ThreadStartTime=2021-03-23 09:04:01)","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Message sent  :WFD-109904  task id is:  7 current time is:  1616490241784   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:04:01.784","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-4","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Execute method of quartz completed:WFD-109904, scheduled fire time:  Tue Mar 23 09:04:00 UTC 2021  current fire time:  Tue Mar 23 09:04:01 UTC 2021 JobDetail 'Event Manager:NULL.Event ManagerTask ID:7:NULL':  jobClass: 'com.xxx.KJob concurrentExectionDisallowed: false persistJobDataAfterExecution: false isDurable: true requestsRecovers: false   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:04:02.313","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-6","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Execute method of quartz started:WFD-109904, scheduled fire time:  Tue Mar 23 09:04:00 UTC 2021  current fire time:  Tue Mar 23 09:04:02 UTC 2021 JobDetail 'Event Manager:NULL.Event ManagerTask ID:8:NULL':  jobClass: 'com.xxx.KJob concurrentExectionDisallowed: false persistJobDataAfterExecution: false isDurable: true requestsRecovers: false   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:04:02.314","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-6->ThreadContext(ThreadStartTime=2021-03-23 09:04:02)","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Putting keys:WFD-109904  task id is:  8 current time is:  1616490242314   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:04:02.316","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-6->ThreadContext(ThreadStartTime=2021-03-23 09:04:02)","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Put operation  completed:WFD-109904  task id is:  8 current time is:  1616490242316   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:04:02.316","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-6->ThreadContext(ThreadStartTime=2021-03-23 09:04:02)","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Sending message  :WFD-109904  task id is:  8 current time is:  1616490242316   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:04:02.328","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-6->ThreadContext(ThreadStartTime=2021-03-23 09:04:02)","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Message sent  :WFD-109904  task id is:  8 current time is:  1616490242328   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:04:02.328","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-6","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Execute method of quartz completed:WFD-109904, scheduled fire time:  Tue Mar 23 09:04:00 UTC 2021  current fire time:  Tue Mar 23 09:04:02 UTC 2021 JobDetail 'Event Manager:NULL.Event ManagerTask ID:8:NULL':  jobClass: 'com.xxx.KJob concurrentExectionDisallowed: false persistJobDataAfterExecution: false isDurable: true requestsRecovers: false   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:05:00.103","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-10","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Execute method of quartz started:WFD-109904, scheduled fire time:  Tue Mar 23 09:05:00 UTC 2021  current fire time:  Tue Mar 23 09:05:00 UTC 2021 JobDetail 'Event Manager:NULL.Event ManagerTask ID:39:NULL':  jobClass: 'com.xxx.KJob concurrentExectionDisallowed: false persistJobDataAfterExecution: false isDurable: true requestsRecovers: false   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:05:00.106","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-10->ThreadContext(ThreadStartTime=2021-03-23 09:05:00)","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Putting keys:WFD-109904  task id is:  39 current time is:  1616490300106   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:05:00.108","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-10->ThreadContext(ThreadStartTime=2021-03-23 09:05:00)","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Put operation  completed:WFD-109904  task id is:  39 current time is:  1616490300108   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:05:00.108","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-10->ThreadContext(ThreadStartTime=2021-03-23 09:05:00)","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Sending message  :WFD-109904  task id is:  39 current time is:  1616490300108   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:05:00.120","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-10->ThreadContext(ThreadStartTime=2021-03-23 09:05:00)","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Message sent  :WFD-109904  task id is:  39 current time is:  1616490300120   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:05:00.120","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-10","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Execute method of quartz completed:WFD-109904, scheduled fire time:  Tue Mar 23 09:05:00 UTC 2021  current fire time:  Tue Mar 23 09:05:00 UTC 2021 JobDetail 'Event Manager:NULL.Event ManagerTask ID:39:NULL':  jobClass: 'com.xxx.KJob concurrentExectionDisallowed: false persistJobDataAfterExecution: false isDurable: true requestsRecovers: false   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:05:00.515","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-3","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Execute method of quartz started:WFD-109904, scheduled fire time:  Tue Mar 23 09:05:00 UTC 2021  current fire time:  Tue Mar 23 09:05:00 UTC 2021 JobDetail 'Event Manager:NULL.Event ManagerTask ID:43:NULL':  jobClass: 'com.xxx.KJob concurrentExectionDisallowed: false persistJobDataAfterExecution: false isDurable: true requestsRecovers: false   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:05:00.516","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-3->ThreadContext(ThreadStartTime=2021-03-23 09:05:00)","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Putting keys:WFD-109904  task id is:  43 current time is:  1616490300516   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:05:00.518","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-3->ThreadContext(ThreadStartTime=2021-03-23 09:05:00)","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Put operation  completed:WFD-109904  task id is:  43 current time is:  1616490300518   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:05:00.518","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-3->ThreadContext(ThreadStartTime=2021-03-23 09:05:00)","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Sending message  :WFD-109904  task id is:  43 current time is:  1616490300518   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:05:00.525","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-3->ThreadContext(ThreadStartTime=2021-03-23 09:05:00)","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Message sent  :WFD-109904  task id is:  43 current time is:  1616490300525   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:05:00.525","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-3","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Execute method of quartz completed:WFD-109904, scheduled fire time:  Tue Mar 23 09:05:00 UTC 2021  current fire time:  Tue Mar 23 09:05:00 UTC 2021 JobDetail 'Event Manager:NULL.Event ManagerTask ID:43:NULL':  jobClass: 'com.xxx.KJob concurrentExectionDisallowed: false persistJobDataAfterExecution: false isDurable: true requestsRecovers: false   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:05:00.744","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-8","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Execute method of quartz started:WFD-109904, scheduled fire time:  Tue Mar 23 09:05:00 UTC 2021  current fire time:  Tue Mar 23 09:05:00 UTC 2021 JobDetail 'Event Manager:NULL.Event ManagerTask ID:42:NULL':  jobClass: 'com.xxx.KJob concurrentExectionDisallowed: false persistJobDataAfterExecution: false isDurable: true requestsRecovers: false   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:05:00.745","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-8->ThreadContext(ThreadStartTime=2021-03-23 09:05:00)","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Putting keys:WFD-109904  task id is:  42 current time is:  1616490300745   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:05:00.748","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-8->ThreadContext(ThreadStartTime=2021-03-23 09:05:00)","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Put operation  completed:WFD-109904  task id is:  42 current time is:  1616490300748   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:05:00.748","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-8->ThreadContext(ThreadStartTime=2021-03-23 09:05:00)","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Sending message  :WFD-109904  task id is:  42 current time is:  1616490300748   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:05:00.756","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-8->ThreadContext(ThreadStartTime=2021-03-23 09:05:00)","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Message sent  :WFD-109904  task id is:  42 current time is:  1616490300756   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:05:00.756","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-8","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Execute method of quartz completed:WFD-109904, scheduled fire time:  Tue Mar 23 09:05:00 UTC 2021  current fire time:  Tue Mar 23 09:05:00 UTC 2021 JobDetail 'Event Manager:NULL.Event ManagerTask ID:42:NULL':  jobClass: 'com.xxx.KJob concurrentExectionDisallowed: false persistJobDataAfterExecution: false isDurable: true requestsRecovers: false   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:05:00.965","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-9","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Execute method of quartz started:WFD-109904, scheduled fire time:  Tue Mar 23 09:05:00 UTC 2021  current fire time:  Tue Mar 23 09:05:00 UTC 2021 JobDetail 'Event Manager:NULL.Event ManagerTask ID:4:NULL':  jobClass: 'com.xxx.KJob concurrentExectionDisallowed: false persistJobDataAfterExecution: false isDurable: true requestsRecovers: false   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:05:00.966","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-9->ThreadContext(ThreadStartTime=2021-03-23 09:05:00)","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Putting keys:WFD-109904  task id is:  4 current time is:  1616490300966   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:05:00.967","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-9->ThreadContext(ThreadStartTime=2021-03-23 09:05:00)","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Put operation  completed:WFD-109904  task id is:  4 current time is:  1616490300967   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:05:00.967","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-9->ThreadContext(ThreadStartTime=2021-03-23 09:05:00)","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Sending message  :WFD-109904  task id is:  4 current time is:  1616490300967   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:05:00.975","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-9->ThreadContext(ThreadStartTime=2021-03-23 09:05:00)","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Message sent  :WFD-109904  task id is:  4 current time is:  1616490300975   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:05:00.976","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-9","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Execute method of quartz completed:WFD-109904, scheduled fire time:  Tue Mar 23 09:05:00 UTC 2021  current fire time:  Tue Mar 23 09:05:00 UTC 2021 JobDetail 'Event Manager:NULL.Event ManagerTask ID:4:NULL':  jobClass: 'com.xxx.KJob concurrentExectionDisallowed: false persistJobDataAfterExecution: false isDurable: true requestsRecovers: false   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:05:01.147","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-2","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Execute method of quartz started:WFD-109904, scheduled fire time:  Tue Mar 23 09:05:00 UTC 2021  current fire time:  Tue Mar 23 09:05:01 UTC 2021 JobDetail 'Event Manager:NULL.Event ManagerTask ID:7:NULL':  jobClass: 'com.xxx.KJob concurrentExectionDisallowed: false persistJobDataAfterExecution: false isDurable: true requestsRecovers: false   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:05:01.148","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-2->ThreadContext(ThreadStartTime=2021-03-23 09:05:01)","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Putting keys:WFD-109904  task id is:  7 current time is:  1616490301148   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:05:01.149","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-2->ThreadContext(ThreadStartTime=2021-03-23 09:05:01)","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Put operation  completed:WFD-109904  task id is:  7 current time is:  1616490301149   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:05:01.149","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-2->ThreadContext(ThreadStartTime=2021-03-23 09:05:01)","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Sending message  :WFD-109904  task id is:  7 current time is:  1616490301149   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:05:01.155","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-2->ThreadContext(ThreadStartTime=2021-03-23 09:05:01)","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Message sent  :WFD-109904  task id is:  7 current time is:  1616490301155   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:05:01.155","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-2","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Execute method of quartz completed:WFD-109904, scheduled fire time:  Tue Mar 23 09:05:00 UTC 2021  current fire time:  Tue Mar 23 09:05:01 UTC 2021 JobDetail 'Event Manager:NULL.Event ManagerTask ID:7:NULL':  jobClass: 'com.xxx.KJob concurrentExectionDisallowed: false persistJobDataAfterExecution: false isDurable: true requestsRecovers: false   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:05:01.319","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-5","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Execute method of quartz started:WFD-109904, scheduled fire time:  Tue Mar 23 09:05:00 UTC 2021  current fire time:  Tue Mar 23 09:05:01 UTC 2021 JobDetail 'Event Manager:NULL.Event ManagerTask ID:8:NULL':  jobClass: 'com.xxx.KJob concurrentExectionDisallowed: false persistJobDataAfterExecution: false isDurable: true requestsRecovers: false   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:05:01.320","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-5->ThreadContext(ThreadStartTime=2021-03-23 09:05:01)","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Putting keys:WFD-109904  task id is:  8 current time is:  1616490301320   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:05:01.322","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-5->ThreadContext(ThreadStartTime=2021-03-23 09:05:01)","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Put operation  completed:WFD-109904  task id is:  8 current time is:  1616490301322   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:05:01.322","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-5->ThreadContext(ThreadStartTime=2021-03-23 09:05:01)","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Sending message  :WFD-109904  task id is:  8 current time is:  1616490301322   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:05:01.326","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-5->ThreadContext(ThreadStartTime=2021-03-23 09:05:01)","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Message sent  :WFD-109904  task id is:  8 current time is:  1616490301326   }
{"ts":"03 23 2021 09:05:01.327","th":"EvtMgrQuartzThread_Worker-5","tenant":"","user":"null","trxid":"","level":"ERROR","logger":"WFC","msg":Execute method of quartz completed:WFD-109904, scheduled fire time:  Tue Mar 23 09:05:00 UTC 2021  current fire time:  Tue Mar 23 09:05:01 UTC 2021 JobDetail 'Event Manager:NULL.Event ManagerTask ID:8:NULL':  jobClass: 'com.xxx.KJob concurrentExectionDisallowed: false persistJobDataAfterExecution: false isDurable: true requestsRecovers: false   }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a property to control the number of triggers to acquire at once by single node **org.quartz.scheduler.batchTriggerAcquisitionMaxCount**, try playing with this number

> The maximum number of triggers that a scheduler node is allowed to acquire (for firing) at once. Default value is 1. The larger the number, the more efficient firing is (in situations where there are very many triggers needing to be fired all at once) - but at the cost of possible imbalanced load between cluster nodes. If the value of this property is set to > 1, and JDBC JobStore is used, then the property "org.quartz.jobStore.acquireTriggersWithinLock" must be set to "true" to avoid data corruption.

[Link to Documentation](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/2.4.0-SNAPSHOT/configuration.html)

[Link to code that acquires triggers](https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz/blob/d42fb7770f287afbf91f6629d90e7698761ad7d8/quartz-core/src/main/java/org/quartz/core/QuartzSchedulerThread.java#L288)